Change domain from softlaunch to production domain?
For soft-launch validation we have created a soft-launch domain, like https://www.softlaunch.client.com and configured Experience Cloud CDN domain for it.
Now we need to update it to production domain.
However, it fails.

How do we do that?
We have verified that https://www.whatsmydns.net/#CNAME/client.com is properly propagated


New domain should be registered in production.
New domain should be activated.
Custom URL should be created pointing to your experience cloud site.
Custom URL from soft-launch domain should be deleted.
Soft-launch domain deployment should be changed to Use a temporary non-HTTPS domain
After this, soft-launch domain can be deleted and removed

https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.domain_mgmt_delete.htm&type=5
